# If I know that something holds pointwise, do I know it holds for an integral over those points?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Say that I have two functions $f$ and $g$, and that I know for every $x \geq y$, $f(x)/g(x) < 1$. Do I know that $\int_{x}^{z}f(x)/\int_{x}^{z}g(x) < 1$ for any $z > x$?

Edit: I don't think this matters, but I want to double check. Is anything different here?

Say that I have two functions $f$ and $g$, and that I know for every $x \geq y > 0$, $f(x a)/g(x) < 1$ where $a > 0$. Do I know that $\int_{xa}^{za}f(x)/\int_{x}^{z}g(x) < 1$ for any $z > x$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if $g$ is assumed a positive function. By the way, your notation $\int_x^z f(x)$ is really very dangerous because $x$ appears twice, once as a constant bound and once again as a "free variable". Just write $\int_x^z f$ or $\int_x^z f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u$, something like that. For your edited question, $\int_{xa}^{za}f$ is $a\cdot\int_x^zf$ and we are no longer guaranteed that $a\cdot\int_x^z f<\int g$; what if $a$ is really rather large? Consider $f\equiv1$ and $g(x)\equiv x$. Consider the interval $[2,3]$. We can choose $a$ to be anything we like, maybe $10^{100}$. Then $f(ax)<g(x)$ is surely true on $[2,3]$ but $\int_{xa}^{za}f=\int_{2\cdot10^{100}}^{3\cdot10^{100}}f=10^{100}$ is much greater than $\int_2^3g=\frac{5}{2}$. :)

You're saying, $f<g$ on $[y,\infty)$ and you're wondering if $\int_x^z f<\int_x^z g$ for $y\le x<z$. If $f,g$ are continuous then this is true, because there is a definite neighbourhood of $x$ (for fixed $x\ge y$) on which not only do we have $f<g$ but $f+c<g$ for a constant $c>0$ (that's important!) and then you can conclude (why?).

If there is no continuity condition you can argue for the same thing measure-theoretically, if you're comfortable with that. $g-f$ is positive and measurable and $[x,z]$ has non-zero measure, $[x,z]=\bigcup_{n\ge1}\{g-f>1/n\}$ holds (inspect pointwise) and by continuity of measure we know $\{g-f>1/n\}$ has positive measure for at least one $n$. This is good enough, since then $\int(g-f)\ge(1/n)\cdot\mu(\{g-f>1/n\})>0$ will hold.

WARNING: $\int(f/g)$ is not the same thing as $\int f/\int g$. Just in case...

Comment: Another warning: $A/B < 1$ isn't necessarily the same thing as $A<B$. (Although it is the same if $B$ is *positive*, of course.)

Comment: @HansLundmark lol. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

I suggest switching to subtraction.... if both functions are positive, you have  $g(x) > f(x) $ and $g(x) - f(x) >0.$  The integral of something continuous and strictly positive is positive, anyway $\int_a^b g(x) - f(x) dx > 0$